# returning a value from a js function using php

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following JS code that calculates a value but is it possible to enter the calc and x values and return them into a php variable like $calcnumber = function calc(l,x)

```
function calc(l,x)
{
    var e=2.71828;
    var p=Math.pow(l,x);
    var g=Math.pow(e,-l);
    var r=1;
    for(y=x;y>=1;y--)
    {
        r=r*y;
    }
    var res=Math.round(((p*g)/r)*1000)/1000;
    return res;
}

function cum()
{
    var l=$("#mn").val();
    var x=$("#rv").val();

    var ss=calc(l,x);
    $("#pd").val(ss);

    var result=0;
    for(var z=x;z>=0;z--)
    {
        result=result+calc(l,z);
    }
    $("#cd").val(Math.round((result)*1000)/1000);
}
```

Comment: by using Ajax yes. another way? Nope.

Comment: PHP and Javascript run on different context, on different computers, not on the same time.

Comment: so the code i have is pointless as I cant return the value to use im my php scripts?

Comment: What processing does the PHP do that you cannot accomplish with JS? You need to figure out if it is worth it to write web service to handle something that could be potential handled completely in the client.

Comment: well really i have my values that are generated by php - i think need to use the value executed from the js further in my php code

Answer (score 0):

Note the comments by axiac and Ron Sims II -

However, there is a way that I have used before with straight JS and PHP -
BUT... it involves reloading the PHP page with the newly calculated JS values passed in the Querystring.

There are only some situations where this is viable -

IE: Load an HTML page from PHP
 - in the JS onload function, calculate some values
 - reload the PHP page with the new values in Querystring
 - (you need some way of telling the JS script NOT to reload 2nd time round)

It has worked for me, but it's not ideal...